# XHTML file reading using HTMLAgilityPack.dll

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am working on C# (windows form based) project. It requires to read the contents from the XHTML files.The XHTML files are stored on the local drive and not on the web. Is it possible to read contents of XHTML pages (without tags) using 'HTMLAgilityPack.dll'? If not is there any other solution for it?

Thanks;
Mayuresh.

Comment: Seriously, what do you expect as an answer except yes or no?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I'm using that library and it works fine. It exposes an API that is similar to .NET's System.Xml.XmlDocument class, except everything is prefixed with Html, obviously. The HTML document tree can be queried using XPath, just like an XML document.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are guaranteed to be valid XHTML (which is XML), then I'd just use `System.Xml.XmlDocument`.

I seem to recall HtmlAgilityPack reads HTML documents and does its best to make it XHTML. You can then work with the document using their DOM and select elements with XPath.